# How to access VS 2010 TFS over the internet from remote office

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

We have a team member in a different country, and are trying to figure out the most viable option to provide them with access to our Team Foundation Server for Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: This is more about infrastructure than programming - should be on Serverfault.com

Comment: Anyways , here is the solutio u need to install teamexplore , packed with VS2010. from there they can access directly the TFS place at anywhere via web

Answer (score 2):

You can check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668967.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If they are part of your corporate LAN/WAN, they *should* be able to get access just like a local user.  If they are external, you have a couple choices:

1. VPN:  You could give them VPN access into your network, then they could access like a local user.
2. Expose:  You could expose TFS to the outside world by allowing the appropriate ports through your firewall.

You can also take a look at the TFS Proxy, but honestly I haven't done anything with that yet.

Comment: The TFS Proxy is only for version control and caches the downloaded files on the remote side to improve the performance for the remote office. 
So it is only to improve performance, but has nothing to do with the actual setting up the remote access.

Answer (score 1):

Open up port 8080 and route that port to the appropriate server. You can also setup to use HTTPS.

When the remote user is not on the same domain, he gets prompted for the credentials. The remote user can use the Windows Credential Cache (Stored Usernames and passwords for Windows XP).

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is to enable TFS through a VPN for WAN users. Through port mapping you can enable TFS application tier access, but the Sharepoint (Documents) and Reports may not work properly. So, the best method is to enable VPS with SSL, and let internet users connect to your TFS just like internal users

Best of luck!