# How do I allow a remote user to access my local TFS server?

Tags: tfs

I'm new to Microsoft TFS and it seems like the default of TFS is connect via a Local Area Network (LAN).

Another team member lives in a different part of the world.  How can I allow him to connect to my TFS Server, which is installed on a Vista Machine so we can share the same project?

Comment: Have you considered moving away from TFS?  You could use Subversion for source control.  This will make this much easier.

Comment: likely duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210476/how-to-access-vs-2010-tfs-over-the-internet-from-remote-office

Answer (score 1):

You can either open up port 8080, or install SSL for TFS. You can find more information how to access TFS remotely at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668967.aspx. It is an article for TFS 2005, but it still applies.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is to set up a VPN, let the user log onto your network and then access the TFS server as you would locally.  This is the way I do it; saves the hassle and security headaches of trying to expose TFS over the internet.