# Expose MS Team Foundation Server 11 from home computer to Internet

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Please help me with my noobish problem

I have laptop at home. I installed MS Windows Server 8 Beta on it, Visual Studio 11 Beta and MS Team Foundation Server 11 only for version control of my application, which I want to change at home (where my laptop-server is) and at work (where my another Visual Studio 11 Beta is).

So my major problem is that I can't easily expose my [home] TFS Server on Internet that I can see it from my work computer :(

I installed TFS Proxy, which generated a proxy URL for me like this: http://win-jnkseeeq4rl:8081/ (which works on LAN)

But of course, I can't get it to work on another (work) computer through Internet, because it doesn't resolve this kind of host.

At home I've got WiFi-router through which my laptop connected.
I think I must expose some ports on it, but I don't know how and is this a main problem really.

Thank you everyone for answers!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run a TFS at home to support my consulting and have setup Remote Access Services using the PPTP protocol to run my inbound VPN.  You generally just have to enable PPTP passthrough (GRE protocol) and forward TCP/1723 to your RAS server.

I also use Dynamic DNS to help find my public IP if it ever changes.

But I have to be honest, have you considered just using the TFSPreview.com service instead?  I haven't switched over completely yet because I've already built my infrastructure and it's still a beta service but I could see myself doing it in the future.

Comment: Thank you for answer!! I think you have as type of connection as I need. But can you tell me what buttons do I need to push? Please :)

Comment: I checked TFSPreview.com - very interesting resource, but it needs to get an invite for registration :(

Comment: Check and see if this is still valid: "TfsDecUpdate"   Otherwise, email me and I'll send you one. They aren't that hard to get.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the walkthrough here => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668967.aspx

There is a similar question here, [How to access VS 2010 TFS over the internet from remote office](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210476/how-to-access-vs-2010-tfs-over-the-internet-from-remote-office)

Comment: Yes, I did look at this walkthrough, but it has no step-by-step recommendations at all. I think I need to set TFS proxy, but I don't understand what buttons to click :). If only you can tell me how I can do that.....