# Can Visual Studio Online synchronize with TFS on a given project

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

We have a project source-controlled by local TFS installation (both are 2013 version). 
The scenario that we want to accomplish is:

1. Developers located in the company use the local TFS as usual.
2. When they finish they check-in the code to the local TFs and Visual Studio Online.
3. Developers working from outside the company, get latest from the Visual studio Online.
4. When they finish, they check-in the changes back to Visual Studio Online.

The target is to have local and online code repositories that can be synchronized either manually or automatically. Is this possible using Visual Studio Online? If not, are there any workaround to achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can synchronise the work using the TFS Integration Tools. They are complicated to setup and will be painfull to run. There are commercial options that are ridiculously expensive, like OpsHub, and I would suggest you just pick a server.

Either have your local server with remote users on VPN, or have a VSO server that everyone accesses. I would recommend VSO with local Build servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can check here. [How to access VS 2010 TFS over the internet from remote office](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210476/how-to-access-vs-2010-tfs-over-the-internet-from-remote-office)
It is about vs2010 but i guess the second answer is for you.